# Recreating the curves tool in photoshop with a fragment shader

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

Im having real trouble recreating the curves tool (aka newb) in photoshop using a fragment shader:

[image: Photoshop Curves Tool]

How would I go about creating an S curve like the one above on the blue channel?

Comment: Did you already search and find the mathematical formula for creating the curve? Can you share your current shader implementation that isn't quite working?

Answer (score 3):

At first, create a curve equlation, see the following link.
http://www.developpez.net/forums/d331608-3/autres-langages/algorithmes/contribuez/image-interpolation-spline-cubique/#post3513925

Then save all the 256 points into a array.
Subscript stands for x,and value stands for y.

Replace old color value with new.

```
int curvePoints[256];

for (int i = 0; i< image.width * image.height; i++)
{
  image[i].blue = curvePoints[image[i].blue];
}
```